# Did the Sorting Hat see the Slytherin side of Harry Potter because of his status as a pseudo-Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter

Did the Sorting Hat see the Slytherin side of Harry Potter because of his status as a pseudo-Horcrux? Could it sense Voldemort's soul shard (who was a Slytherin) within Harry?

Comment: Short answer : Yes.

Comment: What an excellent question! (Only super smart people ask this particular question! ;) )  :)